# Logrotate not writing to new .log file

Tags: systemd, logrotate

I have 4 custom systemd services that write to custom logs in `/var/log/`. I set up a `logrotate` config file, but it is not writing to the newest log. It is still writing to the old `.log.1` file. The new ones are **created**, just no data.

Here is my logrotate config:

```
/var/log/dealer*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 7
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        su root root
        postrotate
        /bin/systemctl reload dealer*.service > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
        endscript
        create 0644 root root

}
```

The newest log files are empty:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root      root               0 Jul 12 11:39 dealerF2f.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root      root               0 Jul 12 11:39 dealerOutbound.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root      root               0 Jul 12 11:39 dealerTimeout.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root      root               0 Jul 12 11:39 dealerWeb.log
```

It is still writing to the `.log.1`:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root      root             36M Jul 12 12:52 dealerOutbound.log.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root      root            9.2M Jul 12 12:52 dealerF2f.log.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root      root             19M Jul 12 12:52 dealerWeb.log.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root      root            171M Jul 12 12:52 dealerTimeout.log.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I see something like this when a process still has the file open - it will continue to write to the old file until the process is restarted.

My bet is that if you do a restart instead of a reload it will work as expected.

If you cannot restart the process completely look into the copytruncate option instead of the postrotate script.

> copytruncate
> Truncate the original log file to zero size in place after creating a copy, instead of moving the old log file and optionally
> creating a new one.  It can be used when some program cannot be told to close its logfile and  thus  might  continue  writing
> (appending)  to the previous log file forever.  Note that there is a very small time slice between copying the file and trun‐
> cating it, so some logging data might be lost.  When this option is used, the create option will have no effect, as  the  old
> log file stays in place.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid a full restart since my `ExecStopPost` calls a bash script that sends an email, however, using copytruncate and removing the postrotate section did what I needed. It created the new log, and began writing to it correctly. Thank you very much.

Comment: `copytruncate` is a last resort as its design is flawed (because it's the best that can be done given the requirements). The services really should be capable of supporting log file rotation properly.